# Renaming a XML File from another server using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, file-rename, xp-cmdshell

I'm looking for a way to rename an XML file from another server.

I'm currently able to do this locally with the code below but now need to rename the file from a different server.

```
DECLARE @Rename NVARCHAR(2000)

SET @Rename = 'ren "D:\Example\ExampleFolderPath\' + @OriginalFileName + '"' + '  "RENAMED_FILE.xml"'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @Rename
```

Comment: Honestly, why do you want to do this in T-SQL at all? SQL isn't a scripting language. You should be doing this in something that is designed to do such tasks, such as Powershell.

Comment: Generally this is not recommended, but if you must. You need to use the UNC path for the folder path (something like "\\servername\path") or map the network drive to a letter on the machine where SQL Server is running, and then use that letter. Also need to ensure the service account has access. Assuming your using AD, you can use ```EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'whoami'``` to figure out what account is being used to access the folder